# How to call a function when node server is up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I want to call a function when the net.serverCreate is up. It need to call this function when the server is started and not when a new connection appears. Event 'listening' dont fire...When I start the server I want to check something in Mysql data-base... How to execute functions when server starts?
My app:

```
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on('listening', function () {
        console.log("Console is listening! "); //Its dont log
    });


    socket.on('data', function (message) {      

    });

    socket.on('end', function () {
        socket.end();
    });
});
server.listen(1337,function(){ 
    console.log("Server starts succefully"); //Its working!
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Event 'listening' dont fire

The callback to `createServer` is handed a **client** `Socket`. Client-side sockets don't listen for requests; they make requests. So a `listening` event is never emitted by `Socket`s

On the other hand, `net.createServer()` returns a **server-side** socket(similar to Java's `ServerSocket`)

This should work.

```
server.listen(1337,function(){ 
//mysql db query
});
```

The callback to listen is executed when the server is bound to the specified port, i.e., when the server starts listening. The last parameter to listen is added as a `listener` for the listening event.

Another way to monitor the server-start event is:

```
server.on('listening', function() {
//mysql db query
});
```

[Listening event](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_listening)